# quicksort algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I have a quicksort algorithm in python that I am trying to implement but for some reason it is not sorting it correctly and I am really confused why. I think it might be because of the random number. I have pasted the 3 functions below.  I am rather new to python so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import random


def swap( l, i, j ) :
 "swaps elements at indices i, j in list l"
 tmp = l[i]
 l[i] = l[j]
 l[j] = tmp

def partition( L, b, e ) :
    "Return: index of pivot"
    # move pivot element to L[0]
    swap( L, b, random.randint( b, e ))
    last = b
# Move <p to left side, marked by `last'
    for i in range( b+1, e+1 ) :
         if L[i] < L[b] :
            last += 1
            swap( L, last, i )
         swap( L, b, last ) # restore pivot
         return last

def qsort( L, b, e ) :
    # base case
    if b >= e : # nothing to do - 0 or 1 element
        return
    # partition returns index of pivot element
    piv = partition( L, b, e )
    #print piv
    # Note that the pivot is right where it belongs
    # It does not get sent out in either call
    print L
    qsort( L, b, piv-1 ) # elements in [ b, piv )
    print L
    qsort( L, piv+1, e ) # elements in ( piv, e ]
    #print L
```

Comment: You don't need a `swap` function in Python. You can replace `swap(L, last, i)`, for example, with `L[last], L[i] = L[i], L[last]`. (At the very least, you can use the simple assignment as the body of your `swap` function, without needing a temporary variable.)

Comment: If you think the problem is the random number: quicksort works fine without it; it's only there so you can't generate pathological worst-case inputs as easily. So just try it without randomizing and see if it works. (In particular, the traditional starting with pivot=0 means already-sorted lists are worst-case. So don't test that case if you use that pivot.)

Comment: @chepner If he does, he'll have to be careful to not call `random.randint()` twice on the first swap in `partition`.

Comment: Meanwhile, is your `b, e` supposed to define a half-open range, or a closed range? Because I think it's half-open sometimes (e.g., `if b >= e`), and closed other times (e.g., `randint(b, e)` instead of `randrange(b, e)`), which could be your problem.

Comment: I tried taking out the call to `randint` and just replacing it with `e` and it still didn't sort correctly...

Comment: @abarnert so what should I do to fix that?

Comment: Well, do you want half-open ranges or closed ranges? Pick one, and make sure you're using it consistently.